# Including the hostname in a HTML file served by nginx

Tags: nginx

Does nginx offer a way to add the hostname (and port) in an HTML file (without using other solutions, such as PHP)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be [SSI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) is what you are looking for?

All variables, which available in core module also available in ssi module.

Usage example:

```
<!--# echo var="host" default="unknown_host" -->:<!--# echo var="server_port" default="unknown_port" -->
```

I had put this string inside test.html and invoke this page through `http://localhost/test.html`

As a result I get following string:

```
localhost:80
```

Comment: I'd like to retrieve it automatically, maybe a nginx-provided variable I can drop in. I could resort to get it from a hardcoded HTML file if there's no other way, but I'm curious to see if there's some other option.

Comment: Well, something like the $date_local or $date_gmt variables offered by SSI, but with hostname and port

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can find example of usage SSI module

Comment: Don't forget to add ssi  on; to nginx.conf